# Load another page in jquery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code is:

```
<div class="ui-widget photo">
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
         <h2>St. Stephen's Cathedral</h2>

         <h3><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=vienna,+austria&amp;z=11" data-geo="data-geo">Vienna, Austria</a></h3>

    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

My Javascript code is:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "[href]",
        content: function () {
            var element = $(this);
            if (element) {
                var text = element.text();
                var link = element.attr('href');
                // alert(link);
                return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
                    "' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
                    "zoom=11&size=350x350&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&center=" +
                    "Vienna, Austria" + "'>";

            }

        }
    });
});
```

This thing is given here :

[jQuery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content)

But Now I want to load another page from another url say : **www.google.com** in this tooltip.

what I am doing is:

I am putting **.load()** function in this content section so that I can get response html and return it into the tooltip

Here is my code but its not working I am getting nothing in response ...

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "[href]",
        content: function () {
            $('#result').load('http://stackoverflow.com/', function (response, status, xhr){
                var responseText = response;

            });
            var element = $(this);
            if (element) {
                var text = element.text();
                var link = element.attr('href');
                // alert(link);
                return responseText;

            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: :eyeroll:  You're going about this wrong.  If you really want to show content from another domain without modification, you'll have to use and iframe, and that is only if the website itself allows its content to be displayed within an iframe (there's a response header relating to frames which allows or denies visibility -- I forget the specifics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load('http://stackoverflow.com');`

Won't return anything because you're trying to load another web site. That's against how AJAX works.

[From jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted.

It allows the user to load a file on the same domain, not external ones, for security reasons.
If you observe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/DfD4m/) with firebug opened you can see that the call will return header `200 OK` but will not load anything due to these restrictions.


To achieve what you want you could make a local file that fetches the desired page, then make an ajax call to it, instead of a directly calling the web site.

---

A simple example of using local php file to get the page.
Create a local file, I'll call it `foo.php`

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); 
   // this will echo contents of given url
?>
```

*Mind, this is only an example code and is not for serious use*

Then call it like this

`$("#container").load("foo.php?url=google.com");`

Comment: If the domain is same..then it will work??Can you give the code snippet for your idea?

Comment: I putting **$("#foo").load('http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/DfD4m/');** still its not working.If site is restricting then could you please give me working example..??

Comment: To test ajax calls on jsfiddle check the "Ajax requests" tab on the left side of the page.

Comment: If you're talking about jsfiddle, that's because you're not parsing the data. It calls the data fine, here's an example of me calling `/echo/xml/` - http://i.imgur.com/FEQ0PSB.png

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you with java. You should try googling for it or try the link Gautam provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to make a `CORS` (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) request.
And because of security concerns such requests are not entertained by browsers and servers unless the server returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the requesting domain acceptable to it.

To know when does `CORS` come into play read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

To know more about `CORS` read the following article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/.

To test if the server supports `CORS` you can use the following website: http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client

An alternative would be to make a `PHP proxy` on your server and then make a `CORS` request through that proxy.

Here is a tutorial for creating your own PHP proxy http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: I want this thing in J2EE.

Comment: See the following tutorial to know how to setup a 'CORS AJAX Proxy' using J2EE http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/access-control-origin-not-allowed.html